# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when trying to print

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, printing, nsprintoperation

So, I'm trying to test the **printing function** and I keep getting a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error pointing me at this part of the code :

```
[op runOperationModalForWindow:(NSWindow*)[core window]
                      delegate:self
                didRunSelector:
 @selector(printOperationDidRun:success:contextInfo:)
                   contextInfo:NULL];
```

The above piece of code is straight out of Apple's developer documentation.

I've put a breakpoint before this code block, and it seems that `[core window]` is absolutely NOT `NULL` and allocated.

**So, what's wrong? Any ideas?**

---

**UPDATE :**

Tried this :

```
[self setPrintView:[[[NSTextView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0,0,200,200)]
  retain]];

[[self printView] setString:[[[[core editor] currentDocument] editorView] string]];
[[self printView] setHidden:NO];

NSPrintOperation *op = [NSPrintOperation
                        printOperationWithView:[[self printView] retain]
                        printInfo:nil];

[op setCanSpawnSeparateThread:YES];
[op setShowsPrintPanel:NO];
[op runOperation];
```

And I'm now getting :

```
*** -[NSStorage insertElement:atIndex:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x121267ff0
```

Comment: I would recommend *enabling zombies* to see if any objects are being over-released.

Comment: Has op already been released? EDIT: I also agree with @trojanfoe, zombies help a lot.

Comment: @trojanfoe I've enabled *zombie objects* but I don't see anything in the console...

Comment: @trojanfoe I've made some changes; have a look.

Comment: Try running the code analysis tools provided with xcode

Comment: Why are you creating a new view, with an arbitrary frame? Why are you retaining something which you've just alloc'ed and init'ed? Why are you retaining it again when you pass it into `+printOperationWithView:printInfo:`? This all seems very wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I just found it :**

The trick is to `release` my `NSTextView` at the end of the printing function.

```
       ...
       [printView release];
}
```